# PHP String Split Problem

Tags: php, string

I'm having trouble figuring out how to split a string into groups of like characters. I have a few strings of rather random character groups similar to this one:

> aaabb2222eee77777

I would like to be able to split them like so:

> aaa, bb, 2222, eee, 77777

and then be able to count the number of characters in each set. What would be the easiest way to do this? I'm really not sure where to start. Thank you!

Comment: Is "aaabbaaa" supposed to be split into "aaa" "bb" "aaa", and each counted individually?

Comment: Yes, each clump should be treated as an individual set to be counted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can then iterate through the array and get the [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) of each item:

```
preg_match_all('/(.)\1*/', 'aaabb2222eee77777', $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];
```

```
Array
(
   [0] => aaa
   [1] => bb
   [2] => 2222
   [3] => eee
   [4] => 77777
)
```

Comment: I'd used almost the same regex but with `preg_split()`... silly me. +1

Comment: And I was trying to do it with a loop... +1